# Leaflet dragging display issue

Tags: leaflet, xojo

I have an application which displays several layers on a Leaflet map.
I create GeoJSONS from a database, then create layers from those GeoJSON and then i put my layers on LayerGroups.

On zoom/dezoom, i add or remove layers from their group to show only some layers.
Everything is fine except sometimes, when i drag my map, some elements disappear.

**before dragging:**

[image: before dragging]

**after dragging to the right:**

[image: after dragging to the right]

**after dragging to the original position:**

[image: after dragging to the original position]

This happens even if i put only 2 layers on my map.
I have tested not to remove my layers but to change the feature style (fill to 0, stroke to 0 for POLYGON layers) but nothing changed.
Has anyone an idea of what can cause this ?

Comment: Can you create a example page?

Comment: You can download the ZIP example at this address : http://example.solutions-sistec.net/example/example.zip

Comment: What tiles are you using?